# How to compare filed values in JOLT transformation?

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I have the input like below,

Input:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2
}
```

Spec:

```
[
 {
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "a": {
      "@(2,b)": {
        "#Matched": "result"
      },
      "*": {
        "#Not Matched": "result"
      }
    }
  }
}]
```

Output:

```
{
 "result" : [ "Matched", "Not Matched" ]
}
```

Expected:

```
{
 "result" : "Not Matched" 
}
```

Can anyone please suggest me help to work it as usual.

Answer (score 1):

You can transform it in three steps:

1. move values to keys
2. find matched key
3. add "Not match" result if matched key was not found

(can't imagine why it doesn't work with values)

Smth like:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&.@0"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "a": {
        "*": {
          "@(2,b.&)": {
            "#Matched": "result"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "result": "Not Matched"
    }
  }
]
```